# Python equivalent for JavaScript Linear duplicate function

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I am new to programming and I am trying to follow along to a data structure and algorithms tutorial, but the author of the book is using JavaScript in the code example below. I'm not looking for ways to improve the code below, and I can conceptually understand what's going on, but I am struggling with how exactly would I implement this line for line in Python.

```
function hasDuplicateValue(array) {
var existingNumbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(existingNumbers[array[i]] === undefined) {
        existingNumbers[array[i]] = 1;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
 }
 return false;
}
```

particularly this code block here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
if(existingNumbers[array[i]] === undefined) {
existingNumbers[array[i]] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't say it's Pythonic but to stay really close to what Javascript does with the list :

```
def has_duplicates(array):
  # define a list with a number of values equal to 
  # the maximum value inside the array; every value equal to None first.
  # if we have 44 in the list we should be able to set the element at position 44 to 1. 
  existing = [None] * (max(array) + 1)
  # iterate on all the elements e in the array
  for e in array:
    # if e has never been seen
    if existing[e] == None:
      existing[e] = 1
    else:
      # e was already seen once
      return True
  # No duplicated value in the array
  return False
```

A shorter version could be :

```
def has_duplicates(array):
    return any(array.count(e) > 1 for e in array)
```

Comment: wouldn't existing be a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you're right, `existing` is a dictionary.
It would have been possible to do the same with a list but it's better with a dictionary (index).

Comment: I believe its supposed to be an array where a value of 1 is placed at the indexes where the numbers are found in existingNumbers

"For example, if the given array is [3, 5, 8], by the time the loop is finished, the
existingNumbers array will look like this:
[undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, undefined, 1, undefined, undefined, 1]
"

Comment: We can see in your code; at the beginning it's empty : var existingNumbers = [];
Then, for each element of the list you check if the element is in the dictionary; if not you get undefined and you add it with a value of 1.

Comment: Ok; I see what you mean you're right. I update the code.

Comment: I have updated the code but that's not really the way to do it using Python. It's strange to try to copy how Javascript does it using Python. The more straightforward the better.